# How to select an action depending on the value of a pair of enums?

Tags: c++, software-design

I'm implementing a model of a protocol in C++ (cache coherency protocol to be particular, but it does not matter for this question)

The protocol takes two values :  a `previous_state` and a `message_type`. Both are enums. The protocol should select a unique action for each combination of the two inputs. Some combinations are invalid (an error should be displayed), and a few combinations are to be stalled.

**What is a good way to code the above scenario in C++?** I can think of : Two nested switch blocks to select an input combination, and call a particular action implemented as a function.

**Is there some more elegant and flexible way to code the above scenario? It should ideally be easy to add/remove input combinations from the protocol.**

Thanks for any advice. (I'm new to design patterns, and don't know any that fits here)

Comment: Not sure but maybe signal-slot?

Comment: Possible use std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::function<void()>> , if signature of the action functions are the same.

Comment: @hmjd: and if you don't care very much about performance.  Which the OP very well may not....

Comment: This is screaming polymorphism.

Comment: If you want to model this using polymorphism, you should also take a look at the "Visitor Pattern", a.k.a. "Double Dispatch". Also, if you have a state and the message transfers it to a different state, you have a state machine, for which there are libraries out there to model them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the two enums are 32-bit values.  I'd do something like this:

```
void doit(E1 previous_state, E2 message_type) {
# define COMBINE(_x_, _y_) (static_cast<int64_t>(previous_state) << 32 | message_type)
  switch (COMBINE(previous_state, message_type) {
  case COMBINE(e1value1, e2value1):
    // ...
    break;
  case COMBINE(e1value4, e2value3):
    // ...
    break;
  // ... more cases ...
  default:
    // report error
  }
}
```

Don't assume this will generate faster code though--switch statements are often optimized into jump tables, but tricks like this may defeat that.  If you're mostly interested in the best possible performance, you'll have to experiment and find out which is best on your system (noting that changing the int64_t to a smaller type and minimizing the shifts in my example may have some effect).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I be sure that the two enums are 32 bit? Otherwise the left-shift won't work. I have just declared them like this:  enum StateType{A,B,..} enum MessageType{M1, M2...}

Comment: If you have a C++11 compiler you can do: enum : long {A,B,C};
That will help you categorically determine the size of storage.

Comment: `assert(sizeof(StateType) == 4)` (or `static_assert` if you're using C++11, or `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`).  As for locking in a specific size using C++11 as @PeterR said, you'd want to say `enum : int32_t ...` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use simple 2 dimensional array? For example

```
enum Previous_state
{
state_1 = 0,
state_2,
...,
state_n,
PreviousLastValue
}

enum Message_type
{
type_1 = 0,
type_2,
...,
type_n,
TypeLastValue
}
...

Action actions[PreviousLastValue][TypeLastValue] = {NULL}; 

void SetAction(Previous_state state, Message_type type, Action action)
{
    actions[state][type] = action;
}

void RemoveAction(Previous_state state, Message_type type)
{
    actions[state][type] = 0;
}

void GetAction(Previous_state state, Message_type type)
{
    if(actions[state][type] == 0)
    {
        //display error
    }

    return actions[state][type];
}
```